# Creating my own midpoint rule function in Mathematica

Tags: functions, numerical-integration, summation

I'm building my own function that is basically a midpoint riemann sum, but I cannot seem to get it to work.

Currently I have

```
Mid[f_, a_, b_, n_] := ((b - a)/n)*Sum[(f[i] + f[i+1])/2, {i, 0, n}]
```

I know it is wrong but I cannot figure out how to fix it. I know that when "I" reaches "n" number, the function will calculate for f[N+1] which is not what I want, but I cant figure out how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: change `{i, 0, n}` to `{i, 0, n-1}`?

Comment: It still gives me the wrong answer unfortunately but I think that is part of the solution.

Comment: Is `f[i]` defined?  Please give full code.

Comment: I was using f[x_] := Sin[x] just to check my answer. There is no other code for this.

Answer (score 4):

You have to evaluate `f` at the right quadrature points. This can be done, e.g. as follows:

```
Mid[f_, a_, b_, n_] := With[{h = N[((b - a)/n)]}, 
  0.5 h Sum[f[t] + f[t + h], {t, a, b - h, h}]
]
```

Here is a test:

```
f = Sin;
Mid[f, 0, 1, 200]
NIntegrate[f[t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

> 0.459697
>
> 0.459698

Note that this way, the function `f` gets evaluated twice for each interior quadrature point, so basically, twice as often as necessary. So, this is something that might be improved upon, e.g. like this

```
Mid2[f_, a_, b_, n_] :=  With[{h = N[((b - a)/n)]}, 
  0.5 h (f[a] + f[b]) + h Sum[f[t], {t, a + h, b - h, h}]
]
```